# Jqgrid pager showing only first page

Tags: json, jqgrid, master-detail

I am trying to implement master detail example (http://trirand.com/blog/jqgrid/jqgrid.html). I am able to load the data but the '#pager10' shows only first page. i can change row number but unable to load further pages even after clicking on next button.  I tried 'loadonce: true' as well as 'false' option. here is the jquery script.

```
    jQuery(function($) {
var data=  $('#abcd').text();
var data= data.replace(/[\“\”\″]/ig,'\"');
var data = jQuery.trim(data);
var title = $('#title_for_table').text();
var title = jQuery.trim(title);
if(title=="Sequencing")
{
    jQuery('#genotype').show();
    jQuery("#tableid").jqGrid({
    datatype: "jsonstring",
    datastr:data,
    colNames:['genotype','num_of_variants' ],
    colModel:[
      {name:'genotype',index:'genotype', width:300},
      {name:'num_of_variants',index:'num_of_variants', width:300}
    ],
    pager: '#pager',
    rowNum:50,
    rowList:[25,50,75,100],
    sortname: 'genotype',
    sortorder: "asc",
    viewrecords: true,
    gridview: true,
    height: '250px',
    width: '100%',
    caption:title+" Search Results",
    onSelectRow: function(genotype) {
    if(genotype == null) {
    genotype=0;
        if(jQuery("#list10_d").jqGrid('getGridParam','records') >0 ) {
        jQuery("#list10_d").jqGrid('setGridParam',{url:"simple3.php?genotype="+genotype,page:1});
        jQuery("#list10_d").jqGrid('setCaption',"SNPs of genotype: "+genotype) .trigger('reloadGrid'); }
        } 
        else {
            jQuery("#list10_d").jqGrid('setGridParam',{url:"simple3.php?genotype="+genotype,page:1});
            jQuery("#list10_d").jqGrid('setCaption',"SNPs of genotype: "+genotype) .trigger('reloadGrid');
            }
        },

    }); 

jQuery("#list10_d").jqGrid({ 
       url:'simple3.php?genotype='+genotype,
       datatype: 'JSON',
       mtype:'POST',
       colNames:['SNP id','chromosome','start position','End position','class','reference base','variant base'],
       colModel:[
            {name:'snp_id',index:'snp_id', width:100},
            {name:'chr',index:'chr', width:100},
            {name:'start_pos',index:'start_pos', width:150},
            {name:'end_pos',index:'end_pos', width:150},
            {name:'clas',index:'clas', width:150, },
            {name:'refbase',index:'refbase', width:150},
            {name:'variantbase',index:'variantbase', width:150}
            ],
       rowNum:50,
       rowList:[50,100,200],
       pager:jQuery('#pager10'),
       sortname: 'snp_id',
       height: '400px',
       width: '100%',
       viewrecords: true,
       gridview: true,
       sortorder: "asc",
       caption:"SNPs of genotypes:" });
}
});
```

Comment: Anybody knows solution for this?

Comment: No error in the above jQuesry. . . i changed the page variable in php script. its working fine nw